# Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned

Tags: floats, positioning

Is there any package or a method to force LaTeX to keep floating environments like `table` and `figure` closer to where they are declared?

Comment: You may also try to relax the rules for placement of floating environments, allowing the page to look worse; among others LaTeX requires that there is enough text on the page if the page is not taken entirely by floats.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but: TeX is assuming that you want the environment to float around.  This means that you can't write "This table:", because "This table" may move somewhere else.  Instead, you should write "as in Table ##".  But if you absolutely need the table/figure to appear where you want it, then the answers on this page are for you.

Comment: Have a look here and follow some of the links mentioned: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned . // BTW, providing code is always a good idea, as you know ...

Answer (score 392):

**Easing the float placement by options:**

You could use more positioning options. Not just `[h]`. If you wish to place the figure near, allow more positioning options, for instance by `[htbp]` (here, top, bottom, page). Use a `!` symbol to remove further restrictions. So, in many cases this is sufficient:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
```

**Useful package regarding float placement:**

- [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) introduces a placement option `H` enforcing the placement exactly at that point.
- [`placeins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) provides the command `\FloatBarrier` to limit the floating of figures or tables. You could place such a barrier before and after a listing.
- [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) allows a more clever `\clearpage`, putting the effect off until the page is full: `\afterpage{\clearpage}`

**Completely avoiding a floating environment:**

Package [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) allows to add a caption outside a floating environment, meaning at any place you want. Use `\captionof{figure}{the caption}` (for figures)

Example:

```
text
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{An example image not including a Wombat}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
even more text
```

The `minipage` keeps graphic and caption together, the `center` environment add a bit of white space around the figure.

**Further reading:**

Because it's an important and not easy subject, there's a lot of material to be found, for instance in FAQ collections. There's an extensive document dealing with graphics inclusion, manipulation and placement:

- [Using Imported Graphics in LaTeX and pdfLaTeX](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) by Keith Reckdahl.

The interesting part for your question may be *Part IV: The Figure Environment* beginning on page 55.

There is also Frank Mittelbach's excellent answer describing the floating mechanism and related options in great detail:

- [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020)

Comment: Too bad you can't just disable floats from being inserted in a certain portion of the paper...

Comment: @SamB: You could use `\FloatBarrier` before and after that portion of the paper or `\clearpage` (or variants) before and after.

Comment: +1: what do you think about mentioning the `flafter` package?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: I've added a link to [Frank Mittelbach's float explanation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020), I hope you don't mind. If you do, please feel free to roll back.

Comment: H option in `float` package is very useful to me!

Comment: As @WillRobertson mentions in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2283/8907), graphics and tables may be too large. When resizing isn't an option, I usually combine multiple figures into page sized floats and use `[p]` in combination with `\afterpage{\clearpage}` to place multiple figures on (preferably) right pages. In my opinion, it leads to a document with greater readability.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I was losing my mind over this one.

Comment: Perhaps one should mention the `capt-of` package as a light weight alternative to `caption` if one just wants to use the `\captionof` macro.

Comment: What's the replacement for `table`? I'm using `tabular` and without a `table` wrapper, table sticks too close to the text.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa the same as for `figure`: `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{center}\captionof{table}{<caption>}\begin{tabular}<stuff>\end{tabular}\end{center}\end{minipage}`

Answer (score 112):

Controlling floats isn't difficult once you understand what LaTeX is trying to do with them. Requisite FAQ link: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats

Three things, broadly speaking, will prevent floats from staying close to their definition:

- underspecified position parameters. I recommend always using [htbp] until the document is complete.
- graphics too large. Do you really need a graph 2/3 the page size?
- too many graphics near each other. Once graphics start building up, it just isn't possible to keep the last one near its source location.

Above all, forget about formatting your floats until the document is absolutely finished. You'll produce better results and write the document faster that way.

Comment: +1 for "don't worry until you're nearly done".

Comment: and another +1 for `[htbp]`. Makes hell of a difference from `[ht]`.

Comment: if anyone thinks the faq answer (will provides a link) doesn't say all that's needed, then please feel free to mail the via link at the bottom of the "faq answer page"; i try to keep up with what's said here, but i'm not omnipotent, apparently.

Comment: The FAQ link is broken, and I couldn't find live FAQs when searching tex.ac.uk. Has this resource moved?

Comment: @MaxGhenis — https://texfaq.org

Answer (score 37):

Check out the [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/float.html) package. It adds ability to include `[H]` forced here float placement. You can also select this as automatic default with `\floatplacement{figure}{H}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Example taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297564
\usepackage{float} % here for H placement parameter

\begin{document}

Text before the table.    

\begin{table}[H] % placement parameter H
    \centering % if you want to center the table
    \caption{Table showing \ldots}
    \label{table:ExampleTable}
    % Code for table
\end{table}

Text after the table.      

\end{document}
```

Comment: 2022-11-4 (Happy Thanksgiving): I decided to add an MWE that shows how the `float` package is used.

Comment: This answer was the one to solve my problem

Answer (score 26):

try `\begin{figure}[!htb]`, in nearly all cases it helps. If not then use:

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

it prevents placing floats before the section.

Answer (score 16):

Fairly often all that you need is to declare tables and figures earlier, *before* the first point of reference (for example, one or two paragraphs before the point of reference, or before the previous subsection heading).

Unfortunately, it tends to be a little bit of trial and error. Some kinds of floats need to be declared earlier than others; for example, floats with placement `[b]` are sometimes trickier than floats with `[t]`.

Answer (score 11):

If it is truly critical that your image / table gets placed where you have typed it in the document, then it isn't a float, and why not remove the float environment entirely ie, insert it directly with `\captionof{figure}[...]{...}` for the captions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why a regular caption would not do?

Comment: @einpoklum `\caption` by default only works inside `figure`, `table` (and some other similar environments). `\captionof` (requires `caption` or `capt-of` package) on the other hand lets you add a numbered caption outside these environments.

Answer (score 10):

As @asia1281 mentioned, the `[h]` directive helps. I did not know of `[h!]` before (thanks!), but reading around seems to suggest that it isn't quite forced as there may still be circumstances where LaTeX refuses to put the float right there.

Another thing that may help is one of `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage`. These force all unprocessed floats to be typeset and then a new page or two (with `\cleardoublepage` and some classes). If you wait until your document is written and you are worrying only about apperance, you can put one of these commands at the end of the text on the very bottom of a page to force the outstanding floats to appear right thereafter. This is really best saved for final stages and needs to be redone (or at least checked) whenever the text is edited.

Comment: `\clearpage` is useful in combination with the `afterpage` package to avoid empty space at the end of a page.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks! I'd not know of afterpage. That certainly makes the use of clearpage in these circumstances much easier.

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to specify for LaTeX to place something is by adding an optional argument for position:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
```

where the `[h]` means *here*, or

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
```

where the `[h!]` is for forced here. Do these work?

Comment: `h` means that you allow 'here', but by not specifying `t`, `b` or `p` you don't allow placement at 'top', 'bottom' or a float 'page'. Restricting to `h` makes placement more difficult.

Comment: Also LaTeX ignores you and changes it to [ht].

Comment: @TH. - so does LaTeX always ignore `h`? that's what i deduced after reading this: robjhyndman.com/researchtips/latex-floats. and would you say adding `!` is typically a bad idea? one might argue that LaTeX constraints were designed with optimum readability in mind.

Comment: No, it doesn't always ignore h. What I meant was if you use `\begin{figure}[h]`, LaTeX will spit out a warning that says it's changed the `h` to `ht`. I don't have an opinion on whether adding `!` is a bad idea or not.

Comment: Adding ! will direct LaTeX to ignore some of its rules with respect to number of floats on the page or size restrictions, so it increases the chances that a float fitts into "h" or "t", see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat for a detailed discussion of all the rules